# Because wakelock_windows >=0.2.1 depends on win32 ^3.0.0 and wakelock_windows <0.2.1 depends on win32 ^2.0.0 Version solving failed

Tags: version-control, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

**dependencies:**

wakelock: ^0.6.2
wakelock_windows:

**dev_dependencies:**
win32:

If their is still version solving issues then remove versions and make the packages name empty.

I tried win32: ^5.2.0 with version name and it gives version solving error. So I solved it by removing version.